# How to extend the dots in a table of content up to the page numbers?

Tags: table-of-contents

I tried anything I could to obtain something like the right image where the dots reach the page numbers. But, I always get the left image.

Is there any option to control this?
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

[Sample Code](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PQLBKNCEQE1ByEdRJuQ29LXI8w6rbaeL/view?usp=sharing)

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) This highly depends on the used class and packages, so please post a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: Thank you! 
I have updated my question with the link to my sample code.

Comment: The sample code you posted does show dot leaders for chapter-level headers. If that's not what you want, please clarify your objective.

Comment: Yes, they appear. But what I need is to have the dots reach to the page numbers. I don't want the empty space at the end. Like the right image that I posted.

Comment: I know how to do it using \@dottedtocline.  As a rule, I do not look at links for MWEs.

Answer (score 1):

Your document class is built on top of the standard class `report.cls`. The behavior you describe is hard-wired into this class (in fact into the macro `\@dottedtocline` of LaTeX itself). The following patch probably works for most document classes that build on the standard classes.

Add the following lines after the `\documentclass{...}` command.

```
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd\@dottedtocline{\hb@xt@\@pnumwidth}{}{}{}
\makeatother
```

Here is an example using the `report` class, but it also works for your class (see the end of the answer).

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd\@dottedtocline{\hb@xt@\@pnumwidth}{}{}{}
\makeatother
\begin{document}    
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Test 1}
\section{A}
\subsection{a}
\clearpage
\setcounter{page}{10}
\section{B}
\clearpage
\setcounter{page}{100}
\subsection{a}
\chapter{Test 2}    
\end{document}
```

Compare the output of the patched version

[image]

with the unpatched standard behavior.

[image]

If you replace `report` by your class `USF`, you obtain

[image]

which is what you asked for (as I understand it).